# Readings of「乗んなかった」 and 「また来なね」

Tags: readings, dialects

Could you please confirm the reading of what I think are two instances of a (Kansai?) dialect that I've seen in the same manga chapter today.  The first one (with a context):

> あの車ね、結局、私が買っちゃったんだ。マルコさん買ってもあんまし**[乗]{の}[ん]{ら}なかった**し。

Furigana is mine and shows the reading I would expect there (i.e. that 乗 is read 「の」 and that next ん is a dialect for ら (and the whole thing is a past negative of [乗]{の}る)).

The second instance is

> また**[来]{き}[な]{て}**ね。

I omit the context, but the meaning is unmistakably "come again".  Though this time it could be a contraction of [来]{き}なさい, it doesn't feel like a command in the context, so I suspect the same dialect again.

So, am I right about [乗]{の} and [来]{き} readings, or do I miss it entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct readings are 乗｛の｝んなかった and 来｛き｝なね. This [link](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/7186830.html) might help! I don't know if the origins are from the kansai region but it is often heard on TV and in kantou as well.

ら is often omitted in place for ん because it is easier to say. One good example is 分｛わ｝からない　and 分｛わ｝かんない.

The second one of verb stem + な represents a light-hearted command.

e.g. 食｛た｝べなよ！ Take a bite!

NOTE: Neither of these forms are formal.

Comment: のんかった < is this typo?

Comment: Seen わかんない several times in the same manga, yet it didn't occurred to me that [乗]{の}んなかった is a similar case.  Noted about  [来]{き}な, thanks!

Comment: @naruto Haha, I'm not sure, I feel like both work

Comment: 乗んなかった can be only read as のんなかった. 乗らんかった is another possible sound change of 乗らなかった, but it has to be distinguished.

Comment: @naruto Oh LOL, I corrected the wrong part :P.  Feel free to edit my post next time :)

Comment: "I don't know if the origins are from the kansai region". I find them specifically non-Kansai. In Kansai it's 乗らんかった, 分からん etc. I think of them as Kanto dialect which has made it into colloquial Standard Japanese, but that's just my gut feeling.